# Flexible, configurable input validation in Java (webapp)

Tags: java, validation, web, input

I need to design a flexible mechanism for input validation (in the backend) of a Java servlet-based web application.

It needs to be able to validate against a *fixed value list*, *regex*, *DB query*, etc, and really it should be easy to implement new kinds of checks.

Currently I am thinking along the lines of an `InputValidator` interface which can be implemented to achieve the different validation types. This would then be linked to an input field through an XML file for example.

Interface

```
public interface InputValidator 
{
  public void init( Configuration config, String[] data );  
  public boolean isValid( Input inp );
}
```

Implementation

```
public class Regex implements InputValidator 
{
  ...
}
```

Configuration

```
  <field name="username">
    <validator name="regex">
      <data><![CDATA[^[\w\-\.+\u00DF]+@*[\w\-\.]+$]]></data>
    </validator>
  </field>
```

How do other people design these things? Any sensible best practises out there? Do's and don'ts?
Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use ready-to-go solutions like `Hibernate Validator` for example. JSF has bult-in features for validation (even via AJAX) too. I think that there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks. My project does not use JSF, and very few external libraries. The Hibernate Validator looks promising but it seems to require a strict beans implementation. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, I belive so, as you are putting you constraints as annotations on validated fields.

Comment: Marking your answer as accepted because of the useful pointer to Hibernate Validator.